# Blury and oversized chart

Tags: chart.js, sveltekit

Why is it so blury and oversized?

[image: Chart screenshot]

```js
chart = new Chart(chartElement, {
    type: 'line',
    data: config,
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    color: 'black',
                    font: {
                        family: 'Montserrat',
                        size: 12
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
                titleAlign: 'center',
                titleFont: {
                    family: 'Montserrat',
                    size: 15
                },
                displayColors: true,
                bodyFont: {
                    family: 'Montserrat',
                    size: 12
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas
    style="width: 500px; min-height: 100px; max-width: 100%; margin: auto; position: relative;"
    bind:this={chartElement}
/>
```

I tried to set response to true and changes the width but nothing changes

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a REPL? https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.59.1